# Getting the last non-empty cell across non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I elegantly get the value of the last non-empty cell (i.e. having the highest column value) across a set of columns?

For example, if my set of non-contiguous columns is A, C, F, and my row has the following values:

```
A B C D E F G

9 8 7 6 5   4
```

then the result would be 7 since C is the highest of A, C, F which isn't empty.

I can do this with a bunch of nested emptiness tests for a single cell at a time, but am looking for an elegant solution that can scale well as the number of such columns rises.

Comment: Do the columns in between have content? Could you post a data sample and expected result to make your question easier to understand?

Comment: @teylyn columns in between may have content, but not necessarily have it. I added a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper row and mark the columns to be watched with the value 1 in that row. With the helper row in row 1 and the data in columns A to M, this is the formula used in the screenshot

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$1:$M$1=1)*(A2:M2<>"")),A2:M2)
```

You can hide row 1. To adjust the columns to be "watched", just enter/remove a 1 into the helper row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you get the MOREFUNC addon you can do:

`=MMAX(ARRAY.JOIN(A1,C1,F1),1)`

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)